# Using arp-scan in ubuntu and kali

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, kali-linux, arp

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04 and I have installed arp-scan with apt-get. If I run it I get a list of machines with their IP addresses, MAC addresses and about half of them say the make, others say (Unknown). Recently I booted Linux Kali on the same machine from a USB and Kali comes with arp-scan preinstalled. When I ran arp-scan in Kali I got the same list of IP addresses, MAC addresses and all makes. My question is why and how does Kali gets all the names of makes for machines on my network while Ubuntu seems to have troubles with it?

Comment: Are the versions of arp-scan on Ubuntu and Kali the same?   I would assume that Kali might have a more robust MAC address lookup database  due to the fact that Kali is tailored towards networking and pen testing, but I would only be guessing.

Comment: I have arp-scan v 1.8.1 on ubuntu and kali has 1.9 by default. Can't seem to figure out how to update it on ubuntu though